# Capacitor Splash Screen Not Updating on Android - Still Shows Icon Image

Tags: android, angular, capacitor

I'm developing an Angular app with Capacitor 5 and I'm facing an issue with the splash screen. Despite following the standard procedures to set a custom splash screen and icon image.

```
npx @capacitor/assets generate
```

The app continues to display the icon image for both splash screen and app icon when tested on a device running Android 14.

I Checked `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` directory and I can find my splash screen image `splash.png`.

**I did further steps I found online.**

**1 - I tried defining a custom splash theme in styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**2 - creating a custom splash theme to MainActivity in AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**3 - Transitioned from the splash theme to the main theme in MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Set your main theme here before calling super.onCreate.
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**4 - Cleared the build cache with ./gradlew clean in the Android directory.**

**Finally, This is my capacitor.config.ts file:**

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'capacitor.test',
  appName: 'capacitor-test',
  webDir: 'dist/capacitor-test/browser',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https'
  },
};

export default config;
```

Despite these steps, the splash screen still shows the custom icon image instead of the custom splash image.

Answer (score 0):

After going crazy for couple of days. I realized that after android 12 there's 2 type of splash screen.

**1- Launch splash screen**

This is a default android behaviour and can't be disabled on Android 12+ as it's part of the Android OS.

It appears when a user launches an app while the app's process isn't running (a cold start) or the Activity isn't created (a warm start).

The application icon image will be centered as a splash screen using themes and any animations that you define. note: It can't be fullscreen.

This splash screen is a must for a short period of time and it's properties can be controlled by **capacitor.config.ts/json** file and **@capacitor/splash-screen**

find more here:

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen

**2- Custom splash screen**

This is an optional splash screen that will appear manualy when triggered. In my case I created a component CustomSplashScreen and in the app component I show it after the Launch splash screen.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  showCustomSplash = true;

  ngOnInit() {
    SplashScreen.hide().then(() => {
      // After hiding the native splash screen, show the custom splash screen
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showCustomSplash = false;
      }, 3000); // Adjust the timeout to your preference
    });
  }
}
```

and in the html template I used it

```
<app-custom-splash-screen *ngIf="showCustomSplash"></app-custom-splash-screen>
```

I decided to share my experience as I found it very confusing.